# Xamarin UI Test issue with MasterDetail

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, coded-ui-tests

I have created a Xamarin Forms MasterDetail project and I've started to run some test. All my test on the detail are working perfectly and I'm able to open my Master as well without issue. However, when I try to "Tap" elements inside my Master, my tests are failing as it doesn't found my AutomationID.
This is what I've done:

```
 [Test]
    public void OpenBurgerMenuAndThenHistory()
    {
        app.Tap("Menu");
        app.WaitForElement("Menu");
        app.Screenshot("Burger Menu opened");

        app.Tap("History");
        app.Screenshot("History Page opened");

    }
```

I have no problem to get the Tap on the "Menu" here but unable to get the Tap for "History". I've tried to WaitForElement and even block the main thread as I thought that maybe it was going to fast to get the History but unfortunately It's not working! What can I do?

Comment: You should `WaitForElement` on some element on the detail before proceeding with a tap, when you do WaitForElement what happens?

Comment: Same issue, not able to found the AutomationId="History"

Comment: Can you see it in the `tree` via `repl`